# Is it possible to use the same coding for an iOS app and Android app?

Tags: android, ios

Will I have to edit my code specifically for each operating system? Or any coding will universally run? (remote database query app)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pay a fee of 25$ to register an account.

Source: http://www.androidauthority.com/publishing-first-app-play-store-need-know-383572/

Comment: So there's no way to publish an android app for free?

Comment: No there isn't. The reason is to make it costly to spam the app store with bad quality apps or simply spam.